# lightbox jquery api

Tags: jquery, api, lightbox

you guys know how google code has made a ajax api for certain javascript plugins/libraries? Well, is there one for the lightbox plugin? I want to use it on my website, but I can only link to it (its not on my local server,) but I can't find a link that only gives my the javascript code and not the entire page's code. any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Question isn't that clear. Are you saying that you are only able to link to the Javascript; you can't host it on your own server? If so, you could re-host the javascript on Amazon S3 or some similar service.

Comment: I need to use lightbox on my blogger blog. I (obviously) can't upload lightbox to the blog so I need to link to it. I can link to jquery with this:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js", but I also need to link to lightbox. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) and find it very flexible. Not only does it cater for images, but it also can load in HTML content (via Ajax if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

If it was available to load via Google content network, it would be found at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/...  You can find the list of supported libraries at http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/.

If you are just looking for a lightbox plugin, try the plugin repository at http://jquery.com.  You can find links to the home page for each plugin.  These typically have download links.  For example, one of the plugins you can find is balupton's which can be downloaded from http://github.com/balupton/jquery_lightbox_bal/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

An other version of lightbox can be found [here](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2). It's called slimbox and uses jquery.

Answer (score 0):

We've found the BlockUI plugin to be useful as well. Check out some of the samples to see if it fits your needs.

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing this, check out here:
http://www.high-on-it.co.za/2011/02/adding-lightbox-to-blogger.html

Not sure how... But just found it.